# Standard Deviation and Variance in Sample and Population Formulas for all?

Tags: self-study, variance, standard-error, sample, population

What are the differences between those Population and Standard Deviation and what are their fomulas? I was told that they are different formulas and which situation do you use population or sample?

If a user gives 10 random numbers, would I be using population or sample?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  1) Is this homework? If so, please add the "self-study" tag. 2) Have you tried Googling these terms? Definitions are widely available on the web and in books.

Comment: Thank-you. And yes this is my homework. @PeterFlom

Comment: OK, then, after Googling, if you want to edit your question to reflect any remaining confusion, I am sure you will get some helpful hints.

Comment: The reason, I prefer not to google things is because the pages are very complicated and long for some reason :(. That's why for simple questions, I would prefer to use this one instead since I heard it's really reliable. @PeterFlom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The population variance is the average squared distance from the mean. You use it when you have the [population](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_population).

That is, if you have every member of the population of interest, you compute $\sigma^2 = \bar v = \frac{\sum_i v_i}{n}$ where $v_i = (x_i - \mu)^2$.

(If you're asking about variances of random variables, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) for the details of the relevant formulas)

The sample variance, $s^2$ uses the same formula, but usually the denominator of the average is taken to be one smaller because observations are closer to the sample mean than they are to the population mean, which makes the squared deviations too small on average; replacing $\frac{}{n}$ with $\frac{}{n-1}$ makes them right on average. The $n-1$ denominator version is sometimes called $s^2_{n-1}$ by contrast from the version with the $n$ denominator, $s^2_n$. You use sample variance when you have a [sample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_sample).

The relevant standard deviations are simply the square roots of the corresponding variances.

Comment: So in my case would I be using population or sample? A user gives me 10 random numbers.

Comment: Do you know what a population is (e.g. did you read say the first sentence of the link I gave)? What's the population in that situation?

Comment: I understand the difference between those formulas, in which case n-1 is used in a sample, instead of n. But I don't know whether I should be using n or n-1 denominator in my case.

Comment: The thing is whether a set of values is regarded as a population relates to what you want to treat as a population (it relates to what thing you're interested in making inferences about). Are the values you're presented with *all* of the possible values of interest, or might, for example, a larger set of values have been possible?

Answer (score 0):

OK....

The formulas vary because the population SD has N in the denominator and the sample SD has N-1 in the denominator.

As to when to use each, well.... it's sort of inherent in the names of the two terms; or are you unclear on sample vs. proportion?

Comment: Oh I see. I'm just unsure the major differences between pop and sample.